# Как записать в одну ячйку пару и больше значений

Tags: mysql

Как записать в одну ячйку пару и больше значений из другой таблици?

Делаю запрос:

`INSERT INTO user_access(role_id, resource_id, resolution_id) VALUES (10001), (10001, 10002, 10003, 10004), (10003);`

Запрос нек выполняется, говорит количесво столбцов не соответствует значению в строке 1.

Мои таблици:

```
--
-- roles table
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS roles;
CREATE TABLE roles (
 role_id            int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 role_name          varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_role PRIMARY KEY (role_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE roles AUTO_INCREMENT=10001;

INSERT INTO roles(role_name) VALUES('Admin');
INSERT INTO roles(role_name) VALUES('Editor');
INSERT INTO roles(role_name) VALUES('User');
INSERT INTO roles(role_name) VALUES('Guest');

--
-- resources table
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS resources;
CREATE TABLE resources (
 resource_id         int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 resource_name       varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT FK_resource PRIMARY KEY (resource_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE resources AUTO_INCREMENT=10001;

INSERT INTO resources(resource_name) VALUES('Users');
INSERT INTO resources(resource_name) VALUES('Projects');
INSERT INTO resources(resource_name) VALUES('Programs');
INSERT INTO resources(resource_name) VALUES('Articles');

--
-- permissions table
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS permissions;
CREATE TABLE permissions (
 resolution_id         int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 resolution_name       varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT FK_resolution PRIMARY KEY (resolution_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE permissions AUTO_INCREMENT=10001;

INSERT INTO permissions(resolution_name) VALUES('Create');
INSERT INTO permissions(resolution_name) VALUES('Read');
INSERT INTO permissions(resolution_name) VALUES('Write');
INSERT INTO permissions(resolution_name) VALUES('Delete');

--
-- user_access table
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_access;
CREATE TABLE user_access (
 access_id          int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 role_id            int(11) NOT NULL,
 resource_id        int(11) NOT NULL,
 resolution_id      int(11) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_access PRIMARY KEY (access_id),
 CONSTRAINT FK_access_roles FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles (role_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT FK_access_resource FOREIGN KEY (resource_id) REFERENCES resources (resource_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT FK_access_resolution FOREIGN KEY (resolution_id) REFERENCES permissions (resolution_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE user_access AUTO_INCREMENT=10001;

INSERT INTO user_access(role_id, resource_id, resolution_id) VALUES 10001, (10001, 10002, 10003, 10004), 10003;
```

Comment: Массив int[1] может нужен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы пытаетесь сделать - нарушение первой нормальной формы. РСУБД не поддерживают такой изврат. Каждое разрешение должно быть отдельной строкой

```
INSERT INTO user_access(role_id, resource_id, resolution_id) VALUES (10001, 10001, 10003);
INSERT INTO user_access(role_id, resource_id, resolution_id) VALUES (10001, 10002, 10003);
INSERT INTO user_access(role_id, resource_id, resolution_id) VALUES (10001, 10003, 10003);
...
```